# window load event doesn't fire when jquery included via import

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have blank page with window load event and its working fine until i'm not including jquery library via import(es6 modules) + JSPM(babel transpiler) to get things work, cant find a reason for that, any ideas?

That's all i got in my page:

app.js

```
"use strict";

import "jquery"; // if i remove this event will fire

window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    console.log("loaded");
}, true);
```

and in my html i do the following(in dev mode ofc)

index.html

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="jspm.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import("assets/js/app");
</script>
```

P.S.
I don't have body onload etc in the htmt

SOLVED!

JSPM load modules async only in dev mode, in production mode all modules and libraries already bundled into one file, so thing loads sync and all works just fine. Thank you @T.J. Crowder

Comment: do u get any errors?

Comment: no, nothing at all, clean console :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you'll find that `System.import` imports things *asynchronously*, and so you have a race condition going. When you remove the import of jQuery, your code loads and runs more quickly, letting it happen before the `window.load` event fires. When you have the import, there's a delay running your code (waiting for the jQuery file to be loaded), and you miss the event.

You can easily determine whether that's the case (see comments):

`index.html`:

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="jspm.config.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(event){    // Added
        console.log("index.html - got load event");     // Added
    }, true);                                           // Added
    System.import("assets/js/app");
</script>
```

`app.js`:

```
"use strict";

import "jquery"; // if i remove this event will fire

console.log("app.js running");                          // Added
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    console.log("loaded");
}, true);
```

If you see this:

```
index.html - got load event
app.js running
```

...you know that you missed the event.

If you're targeting modern browsers, you can modify your `app.js` code to handle that case via [`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState#Values):

```
"use strict";

import "jquery";

function loadCallback() {
    console.log("loaded");
}

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    setTimeout(loadCallback, 0);
} else {
    window.addEventListener("load", loadCallback, true);
}
```

(Note that to avoid being chaotic, we **always** call `loadCallback` asynchronously, so that any code following the block above has completed reliably before it is run.)

If you need to support browsers that don't provide `document.readyState`, you'll probably need to hook up your `load` event handler in `index.html` (blech), or alternately use jQuery's `ready` feature. If you use `ready`, beware that it *doesn't* reliably call your function asynchronously (it'll be sync if `ready` has already fired). :-| Also, `ready` fires much earlier than `load` (usually that's a good thing, but if you're relying on images having been loaded...).

Comment: yes, you are completely right, but in production mode i will got only one file, and preferably to me got access to jquery functionality in Loader class which i wanna create, but any way thank you

Comment: @Smile0ff: Yes, if everything is bundled into one file for production, this is a dev-time only issue.

Comment: one more thing that i'm not understand, if `$(function(){})` - as shortcut for jquery ready event is working fine and we know that `window.onload` fires later than ready event, so why it doesn't work with `$(window).load(function(){})`

Comment: @Smile0ff: If you don't hook `ready` until after `load`, it doesn't matter that it originally fires earlier, you still won't get a `load` callback.